# Format a local date at another time zone

Tags: java, date, format

I try to format the current time in 2 locations: Chicago and Tokyo

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime chicago = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("chicago: " + chicago);
System.out.println("Chicago formated: " + chicago.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));

ZonedDateTime tokyo = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println("Tokyo: " + tokyo);
System.out.println("Tokyo formated: " + tokyo.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));
```

The print out:

```
chicago: 2017-11-05T18:19:01.441-05:00[America/New_York]
Chicago formated: 6:19:01 PM EST
Tokyo: 2017-11-05T18:19:01.441+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
Tokyo formated: 6:19:01 PM JST
```

**6:19:01 PM** printed for both Chicago and Tokyo. Why?

Thanks Andreas for make the above code work.
Following your logic I try to make this work:

```
LocalDateTime PCTime = LocalDateTime.now();//Chicago: 7:51:54 PM
ZonedDateTime newYorkTime = PCTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("now: " + newYorkTime);
System.out.println("now fmt: " + newYorkTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));
ZonedDateTime newYorkTime0 = newYorkTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("N.Y. fmt: " + newYorkTime0.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));
```

The output:

```
now: 2017-11-05T19:51:54.940-05:00[America/New_York]
now fmt: 7:51:54 PM EST
N.Y. fmt: 7:51:54 PM EST
```

The last line should be `N.Y. fmt: 8:51:54 PM EST`

Comment: Understand that `LocalDateTime` is *not* a specific moment in time. It is just a rough idea of possible moments available across at least 26 hours around the world. It has no meaning until you supply the context of a specific time zone. Saying "6 PM" has no meaning until you say "6 PM in Chicago" or "6 PM in Tokyo".

Comment: As [**already stated in my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47128331/5221149), calling `LocalDateTime.atZone()` simply *assigns* a time zone, it doesn't *change* the time. `PCTime` is 7:51 PM in *any* time zone, so `newYorkTime` is 7:51 PM EST. If you want to *change* the time, you first have to specify the time zone of `PCTime`, e.g. `PCTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` since the system default time zone was used to obtain the local time, *then* convert to the new time zone using `withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))`, as also shown in my answer.

Comment: Very good explanation!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`LocalDateTime.atZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) means: *Take this local time and consider it to be the local time in this time zone.*

That means that 6:19 PM "local time" in Chicago is ... 6:19 PM in time zone EST, and that 6:19 PM "local time" in Tokyo is ... 6:19 PM in time zone JST.

When you call `LocalDateTime.now()`, you get the local time in your current default time zone, but the returned value don't know what time zone that is. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) says:

> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

If you want to take the current *real* time and see what it is in Chicago and Tokyo, then you need to use either a universal time (`Instant`) or a time that know what time zone it represents (`ZonedDateTime`).

*Using `Instant`*

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime chicago = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("Chicago: " + chicago);
System.out.println("Chicago formatted: " + chicago.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));

ZonedDateTime tokyo = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println("Tokyo: " + tokyo);
System.out.println("Tokyo formatted: " + tokyo.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));
```

*Output*

```
Chicago: 2017-11-05T20:02:45.444-05:00[America/New_York]
Chicago formatted: 8:02:45 PM EST
Tokyo: 2017-11-06T10:02:45.444+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
Tokyo formatted: 10:02:45 AM JST
```

*Using `ZonedDateTime`*

```java
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime chicago = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("Chicago: " + chicago);
System.out.println("Chicago formatted: " + chicago.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));

ZonedDateTime tokyo = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println("Tokyo: " + tokyo);
System.out.println("Tokyo formatted: " + tokyo.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)));
```

*Output*

```
Chicago: 2017-11-05T20:04:19.368-05:00[America/New_York]
Chicago formatted: 8:04:19 PM EST
Tokyo: 2017-11-06T10:04:19.368+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
Tokyo formatted: 10:04:19 AM JST
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I follow your logic and wrote another piece of code. But it does not work. See added code in the original question above.