# Why get different localDate with same timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, java-time

```
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("1900-01-01");
org.joda.time.LocalDate localDate = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(date);
```

Based above code, I did some tests as below:

- Question #1 why do I get different localDate object with same timezone?

If I change local timezone to `UTC+8 Singapore Timezone`, will get `1899-12-31`

If I change local timezone to `UTC+8 China Timezone`, will get `1900-01-01`

- Question #2 why do I get same time with different timezone?

If I change local timezone to `UTC-8 America/Los_Angeles Timezone`, will get `1900-01-01`

If I change local timezone to `UTC+8 China Timezone`, will get `1900-01-01`

Could someone help clarify that?? it is little bit confused.

Comment: I think this link help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128190/format-a-local-date-at-another-time-zone

Comment: how did you `change local timezone`?

Comment: @Sun I changed timezone with "Date & Time Preference"(Mac) in local machine

Comment: The reason for the confusion is that Singapore has changed its time zone six times in history, I happen to be using the time of my example when the Singapore time zone was UTC+06:55 between the 1900 and 1924, because I always thought China and Singapore were the same time zone(UTC+8)

Comment: @HavenLin That answer was assuming that you were constructing `org.joda.time.LocalDate` with specific time zone. I updated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 1900, [Singpore's](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/singapore/singapore) offset is `UTC +6:55:25`, so when you create date  `1900-01-01` in Singapore time zone, it should be `1899-12-31T17:04:35Z[UTC]` as below:

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime localDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(1900, 01, 01, 0,
            0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Singapore"));

System.out.println(localDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
// 1899-12-31T17:04:35Z[UTC]
```

However, when you use `java.sql.Date`, it use wrong offset `UTC +08:00`:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Singapore"));
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("1900-01-01");

java.time.Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
System.out.println(instant);   // 1899-12-31T16:00:00Z
```

and when you create `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` with this wrong value, Joda use `UTC +6:55:25` as offset, resulting in a date time `1899-12-31T16:00:00 + 6:55:25`:

```
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime singaporeDateTime = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(date);
System.out.println(singaporeDateTime);  // 1899-12-31T22:55:25.000
```

---

You can use the similar approach to check the result of Shanghai and Los Angelas, the point is, avoid using `java.sql.Date` and other deprecated date time related classes. Use `java.time` instead if you are working with java8 or higher.

Comment: When using Java 6 or Java 7, use the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project rather than the terrible legacy classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality was successfully back-ported. Nearly identical API allows you to eventually migrate to *java.time* by doing little more than change `import` statements.

Comment: @Sun I agree with you, In 1900, `java.sql.Date` uses wrong offset `UTC+8` for Singapore timezone

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate
.of( 
    1900 , 
    Month.JANUARY , 
    1 
) ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using a terrible old class `java.sql.Date` that was badly designed with flawed hacks. Among its problems is that it *pretends* to represent a date-only value but actually holds a time-of-day. It even holds a time zone deep inside, though without getter or setter. **Never use this class.** Supplanted years ago by the `java.time.LocalDate` class.

The *Joda-Time* project too is supplanted by the *java.time* classes. The project is in maintenance mode, receiving updates and critical bug fixes but no new feature work. The project advises migration to the *java.time* classes. Migration is easy as they share similar concepts, both having been led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

Use `java.time.LocalDate` when you want a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. All your problems raised in your Question go away.

```
java.time.LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1900 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ;  // Simply a year-month-day date, no problems, no issues, no confusion.
```

> ld.toString(): 1900-01-01

Also notice that *java.time* uses sane numbering where `2018` means the year 2018, and 1-12 means January-December. This is in distinct contrast to the troublesome legacy classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion